# How to make payments with Stripe on Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, stripe-payments

Probably there might be other cases containing the same title as mine, but I basically want someone to guide me to accomplish this. I'm currently making an app for my school to allow parents to pay their monthly payment through there, I have a child **(usernames/$usernames/$uid/bill/(months to pay))** in the bill I have each month they have to pay with their values, such as **"price"**, **"month"**, you get the idea, **each user has it's own /bill/**, so how could I somehow link this to Stripe? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Handling payments is not built into Firebase. But you can build it yourself using Cloud Functions and Stripe's API. For the newer Cloud Firestore database, this process is documented in:

- [this video from a Firebase engineer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeyxolsJ3aE)
- [this code sample based on that video](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/stripe)
- [this blog post by a Firebase advocate](https://medium.com/@ThatJenPerson/go-serverless-manage-payments-in-your-apps-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase-3528cfad770)

The sample used to be based on Realtime Database, so you can still find the code for that in [this branch](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/stripe/functions/index.js). The rest of the flow will be the same as above.

Comment: So I if I want to work with firebase as backend for stripe processes I must use firestore? I cant use firebase database?

Comment: Given what I see here it seems you can use either or. https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples#quickstarts

Comment: You can use either of Firebase's databases, or honestly any other database you want. But there is more documentation/prepackaged content for doing it on Firestore/

Comment: I'm familiar with realtime, but not with Firestore. Im also novice with stripe. Which do you recommend I use?

Answer (score 0):

Can see you tagged the realtime database, [here is an example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/stripe/functions) from the google cloud functions using RTDB that shows how to use cloud function triggers to deal with the stripe customer creation, taking payments etc.

Just as a reference if using firestore [here is an example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/stripe/functions)